# App is getting crashed after expo eject in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I created react native app in expo but due to some limitations, need to convert my app to react-native cli using "expo eject". Now when trying to debug my code in react native debugger, app is crashing and not opening. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message it is showing ?

Comment: Check the log in xCode/Android Studio and share it.